# Proving an inequality as $n$ gets large

Tags: inequality

I am trying to show that, for large $n$,
$$\left ( 1 - \frac{\mu}{L} \right )^k \leq \left ( 1 - \frac{\mu}{2(\mu n + L)} \right )^{nk},$$
where all constants are positive, real, numbers. I believe this is true, but if not, I think a condition can be easily found where it is true. This is for an algorithm and not some analysis problem, so a simple algebraic proof is all I am looking for.

My first step was to let
$$a = 1 - \frac{\mu}{L} \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ b = 1 - \frac{\mu}{2(\mu n + L)},$$
and then taking logarithms, we have
$$nk \log(b) \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \  k \log(a).$$
There is some ambiguity when comparing these two values.

My friend said he used the fact that $(1-x)^n \leq e^{-x}$, but I can't see how to get there.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: the majorant tends towards $e^{-k/2}$ as $n \to \infty$, so you should have $a^k \leq e^{-k/2}$.

Comment: What about, say, $\mu=1$, $L=9.6$, $k=0.7$?